# Process.chdir() has no effect on require

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, commonjs, working-directory

Given the structure directory structure:

```
.
├── alpha.js
└── foo
    └── beta.js
```

And file contents

*alpha.js*

```
module.exports = "alpha"
```

*foo/beta.js*

```
var cwd = process.cwd()
process.chdir('../')
var alpha = require('./alpha.js')
console.log(alpha)
process.chdir(cwd)
```

From within `foo/beta.js`. I'd like to be able to trick `require` into thinking that the current working directory is the project root. The example above does not work when the following is run.

```
node ./foo/beta.js
```

However if I switch over the code to within `foo/beta.js` to the following. Reading the file from the system and passing it to the npm module [`_eval`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eval).

*updated foo/beta.js*

```
var path = require('path')
var cwd = process.cwd()
process.chdir(path.join(__dirname, '..'))
var fs = require('fs')
var _eval = require('eval')
var alpha = _eval(fs.readFileSync('./alpha.js'))
console.log(alpha)
process.chdir(cwd)
```

This does work, which proves it should be possible with `require` as well. No matter where you run if from it will always require the file. `node ./foo/beta.js` or `cd foo && node ./beta.js`

Is there any way that I can prepend or set the directory that `require` uses from within the file?

Comment: Why not use `var alpha = require('./../alpha.js')`?

Comment: @DanD. I'm have to execute the code from the parent dir and be able to make the module call with `./alpha.js` that is the technical challenge I need to meet.

Comment: @DanD. The correct string reference from within `foo/beta.js` would be `var alpha = require('../alpha.js')`.

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to do this?  I didn't really follow your comment, and this feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @AaronDufour I wanted to allow a argument to a global module I created called [evalmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/evalmd) that would allow markdown strings with require statements to be executed from a different working dir. So if you run the cmd and you have your md files within `docs` it would work. As an alternative to my question [I just went ahead and prepended the require string with the dir](https://github.com/reggi/evalmd/blob/master/test-markdown.js#L67).

Comment: Do you have control over the target directory?  There might be an easier solution if you can ensure a particular file is there.

Comment: @AaronDufour not sure what you mean by target dir.

Comment: The directory you want requires to be relative to.

Comment: @AaronDufour The what do you mean about control? I'm already passing the target dir in a prepending the path with it, what more can I do?

Comment: "There might be an easier solution if you can ensure a particular file is there [in the dir you want requires to be relative to]" is the relevant part.

Comment: @AaronDufour I don't see how that helps without a solution like @jfriend00 where you craft your own `require` function.

Comment: I was going to post an answer about how that helps, but I won't bother unless it would actually helpful.

Comment: @AaronDufour If you think it might help others. I'm interested but you don't have to go out of your way. I already have a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [node.js doc for `require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html):

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a native module,
>   and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then node starts at the
>   parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and
>   attempts to load the module from that location.
>
> If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and
>   so on, until the root of the file system is reached.

From this, you can see that the current directory is not used in loading modules.  The main takeaway here should be that modules paths are relative to the location of the current module.  This allows modules to load sub-modules in a self-contained fashion without having to know anything about where the parent is placed in the directory structure.

Here's a work-around function that loads a module file descriptor from the current directory if the filename passed to it does not start with a path separator or a `.`.

```
var path = require('path');

function requireCWD(fname) {
    var fullname = fname;
    if (fname && fname.length && 
      !path.isAbsolute(fname) &&
      fname.charAt(0) !== '.') {
        fullname = path.join(process.cwd(), fname);
    }
    return require(fullname);
}
```

Then, any filename you give to requireCWD that is not relative and does not start with a "." will be loaded relative to the current working directory.  If you want to allow even `"."` and `".."` to be relative to the current working directory, then you can remove that test for `'.'` from the function.

Comment: Just to confirm, there is no built in override?

Comment: @ThomasReggi - If you want to load a module relative to the current directory, you can get the current directory and join a filename with it and give `require()` that absolute path.  That would be the work-around.  You could also make yourself a little function (called `requireCwd()` that would do that for you when passed a filename).

Comment: @ThomasReggi - I added a code example for a `requireCWD()` work-around.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @jfriend00. It's sad that this is the only alternative and that `require` needs to be proxied like this. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955383/process-chdir-has-no-effect-on-require/31955686?noredirect=1#comment51820843_31955383) for the solution to my problem.

Comment: @ThomasReggi - Another possible work-around.  Create a module in your current working directory with code in it that invokes the other `require()` statements.  Then, load that module.  The require statements run from within that module will process paths relative to the module directory which could be the directory you want.

Comment: ugh! i'm having this same issue, but this solution won't work for me because i'm trying to require bindings and then get a binding relative to a sub-directory.  it works if I do it from a node shell, but not from a script!

Comment: @Michael - You can just construct an absolute path using whatever sub-directory you want it to be relative to and then pass the absolute path to `require()`.  That's what this answer does for the current working directory, but you can substitute any other path in place of that if you want.

Comment: not sure i understand... i have tried passing the absolute path to the .node file ("Error: cannot find module") and I have tried passing the absolute path to the function returned by `require("bindings")` (it stupidly appends that to "./build", "./out", "./Debug", etc.)

Comment: @Michael - Take the exact code from my answer here and substitute whatever directory you want to be relative to for the `process.cwd()` in my code.  This code avoids things that start with `.` on purpose.  If you don't want it to avoid those, you can remove that test from the code too.